# WordPress Error showing in compat.php

Tags: php, web, wordpress

I am really new to wordpress environment. 
 I have the site on https://www.thewebdebug.com which is showing an error  like

```
PHP Error Message

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/a9739613/public_html/wp-includes/random_compat/random.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/a9739613/public_html/wp-includes/compat.php on line 338
```

can anybody tell me what is going on and how should i fix it.? I had tried on the web but couldnot find a solution that fits my need. I have recently upgraded my wordpress and some plugins failed to do.